# C++ template compiled but not used - mac OS Lion

Tags: c++, macos, qt, templates

I have a very, very weird situation. I code that sorta looks like this :

```
class Foo
{
   public:
   template <class T>
   int doSomething()
   {
         std::cout << "Hello world!";
         // bunch of code
   }
};
```

If I try to call doSomething like this :

```
std::cout << "Pre";
doSomething<int>();
std::cout << "Post";
```

Output:

```
 Pre
 Post
```

I do not get the output Hello World, and nothing in the function is executed. Naturally this means my program crashes a bit later, because I needed to have that function execute.

However, if I do template specialization:

```
template <>
int doSomething<int>()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World int!";
    // more code
}
```

Then my output is:

```
Pre
Hello World int!
Post
```

This doesn't happen on Windows or Linux, only on Mac - and only versions that are compiled on an older version of Mac OS.

Is there something in the standard or as general compiler implementations that can cause this behaviour? Where, if you don't specialize a template, the template is not called?

If I put badly-formed code in the body of the template function, the compiler does throw an error for each template type argument, so I'm confident the code is being compiled. I do not understand why it's not being called though. There are other templates in the codebase that work just fine.

I would post the exact code, but unfortunately I cannot due to company policy. I also don't seem to be able to reproduce if I write some throwaway code!

I know there's not much here, and I'm sorry to ask without providing much in the way of real information, but after extensive googling I'm coming up short. Has anybody encountered anything like this before, and if so, do they know what the hell is going on?

Edit: Compiler version. I thought I already wrote this but obviously didn't! Sorry!

G++ 4.2 (GCC 4.2.1, based on Apply Inc. build 5658)

I am compiling with the same compiler in the command line. However, I am using QtCreator for the main project, where the issue stems. I will update the question to mention it uses Qt, although I doubt it's linked it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: That close vote is stupid, this is a really well defined question. I might not know the answer, but it's really clear what the problem is.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there's a close vote on this. I would very happily provide whatever extra information people might ask for, if I can - I just don't know what else to provide. I am *entirely* at a loss here. I wish I could simply post the codebase, but I can't.

Comment: I don't think it is the os that is the root cause but a faulty compiler or missing compiler options.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck This has been tested on two seperate machines, so I don't think it's an install issue with some corrupted data (but it could be, just I think unlikely!)

Do you know of any compiler options that could cause this? If there is one, and I can fix it, that would be excellent!

Comment: Of course, but on closed systems with compilers included specifying the OS version is usually enough to narrow it down enough.

Comment: If you can't post the full code, provide as much information as you can -  compiler version, the exact OS version, the command line. And when you tried to reproduce, were you doing it on the same compiler?

Comment: @AntonSavin Sorry, I thought I had put the compiler version, but obviously I didn't! I've updated now. Yes, the same compiler across both machines and for my throwaway code (that worked as expected)

Comment: When you say it doesn't happen on Windows or Linux are you also using GCC 4.2.1 on those platforms?

Comment: What is the actual name of the class and function?  What namespace is it in?  Are there any other classes of the same name?  Functions?

Comment: @sjdowling No, more recent version of gcc. 4.8 for Linux, Windows is MSVC++. I do not have the exact version number for that one, sorry - don't have access to the Windows machine right now.

Comment: @Yakk
Actual name of class : statsROI. Function : runStats
Not in a namespace - this project irrationally hates namespaces.
There are no other classes with this name, or any other functions with this name.

Comment: From the [release information](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/) it looks as if the compiler you are using is 8 years old. I'm willing to bet that this is just the fault of a buggy old compiler. Unfortunately using buggy old compilers seems to be a requirement for developing for Apple...

Comment: @sjdowling I fear that you are correct :[ I'm going to try with some other compilers

Comment: Any pre compiled headers or other magic in the project?  Any thing linked in (other source files, libraries, etc) that could possibly (not just ilkely, POSSIBLY) include that header that you did not rebuilt from scratch?  I'm fishing for an inline function name collision causing one implementation to be discarded silently (ill formed program, no diagnostic required).  The specialization would change these rules around a bit (again, undefined behavior, but different ub).

Comment: @Yakk Clean rebuild, __attribute__((noinline)), the full works. No precompiled headers, and nothing calls this template function except the class itself (it could even be private, it's just not right now. Compiles when private so no access horrors)

Comment: @MikeB um, template functions *must* be `inline` (as must methods inside classes) under the standard (and are implicitly such).  I have no idea what trying to force something to be not inline when the standard mandates it must be inline *does*.  `inline` in C++ mostly means "if there are linker collisions, ignore them and pick any one of them".  Probably that attribute has to do with removing function call overhead, which is also called inline: the `inline` keyword makes that easier (by allowing code to be visible in multiple compilation units).

Comment: Are there any tokens that are touched by the preprocessor in that function?  After that, I give up, and think you need to make a small, reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, sorry. You're right - template functions do of course need to be inlined. I doubt that the attribute did anything.

There are no tokens that are touched by the preprocessor. I'm trying to create a reproducible example, but in the meantime also trying with a different compiler (rebuilding the entire app from scratch takes a hell of a long time)

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, I have fixed the problem - but I don't know why it works, and the normal approach doesn't.

The fix was simply to move the template functions into another class that was defined within the .cpp file, where the template functions are being used.

hpp:

```
class Foo
{
   int update(); // this calls the template functions
   FooInternal* d;
};
```

cpp:

```
class FooInternal
{
    template <class T>
    int doSomething()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world!";
        // some code
    }
};

int Foo::update()
{
    d->doSomething<int>();
    // more code
}
```

It's really odd, as this file was only included in one place, and the code was never called outside of the class. Do not understand.